# Simplification of Log Factorial Expression

Tags: logarithms, factorial

I would like to find a simplification of the expression
\begin{equation}
\log{\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x! y! z!}}
\end{equation}
that is linear with respect to $x, y$, and $z$.  Does such an expression exist?

(In case it makes a difference, I know that $x, y$, and $z$ are each nonnegative integers and that they sum to some fixed $n$.)

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: All we know is that the fraction is an integer value (a multinomial coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that the answer is "no".  Consider the simplified expression with only two variables
\begin{equation}
\log{\frac{(x+y)!}{x! y!}},
\end{equation}
where $x+y=n$.  This can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
\log{\frac{n!}{x! (n-x)!}}.
\end{equation}
Plotting this function for $n=5$ gives

[image]

which is clearly nonlinear with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\log x! = \log (1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot (x-1)\cdot x)= \sum_{i=1}^x \log i$. Thus we can do the following  simplification, using the regular logarithm rules for handling multiplication and division.

$$\log{\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x! y! z!}} = \log (x+y+z)! - \log (x!y!z!) = $$ $$= \sum_{i=1}^{x+y+z}\log i - \sum_{i=1}^{x}\log i - \sum_{i=1}^{y}\log i -\sum_{i=1}^{z}\log i $$
It is not linear with respect to $x,y$ and $z$ though, but it is, in some sence, an easier expression.